# How to perform Z transformation on this difference equation？

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

The difference equation is as follows：
$$E(i+1)=(I-AT)E(i)+1/2(AT)^2$$
Where, $E$ and $A$ are matrices.

This is part of the code I wrote using Mathematica:

```
A = {{0,-1/l}, {1/c,-1/(r c)}};
B = {1/l,0};
S = Inverse[DiagonalMatrix[{1,1}]-stepsize*A];
Error = Transpose[{{ilerror, vcerror}}];
ZTransform[{Error[i+1]-S.Error[i]-1/2*stepsize*stepsize*A.A==0,Error[0]->0},i,z]
```

I want to use the **ZTransform** command to perform Z transformation on the difference equation. How should I write or modify my code? Or this command cannot process the matrix?

Comment: ZTransform input is an expression not an equation.

Comment: @DanielHuber I have changed it to an expression, but I still couldn't get the correct Z transformation.

Comment: How about `A = {{0, -1/l}, {1/c, -1/(r c)}};
B = {1/l, 0};
S = Inverse[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}] - stepsize*A];ZTransform[{{ilerror[i + 1], vcerror[i + 1]} - 
    S . {ilerror[i], vcerror[i]} - 1/2*stepsize*stepsize*A . A}, i, 
  z] /. {ilerror[0] -> 0, vcerror[0] -> 0}`?

Comment: @user64494 I tried to compile it, but the result still contains *ZTransform*, which is not completely transformed.

Comment: Yes, of course since `ilerror[i]` and `vcerror[i]` are not known. See "Applications"  in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ZTransform.html?q=ZTransform for a similar example. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 OK, thank you! Let me check it.